# React native router flux don't receive the param

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have used react native router flux, I want to pass the params to another page.

I have two page, home page (list of item) and detail page (detail of item).

I want to passing the item_id to detail page for fetching the data from API.

This is home page code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, List, ListItem, Thumbnail, Text, Left, Body, Right, Button } from 'native-base';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>

                    <List>
                        <ListItem thumbnail>
                            <Left>
                                <Thumbnail square source={require('../img/logo.png')} />
                            </Left>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>code</Text>
                                <Text note numberOfLines={1}>description</Text>
                            </Body>
                            <Right>
                                <Button transparent>
                                    <Text onPress={() => Actions.detail({ item_id: 1 })}>View</Text>
                                </Button>
                            </Right>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is Detail page code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion, CardItem, Body, Card, Left, Thumbnail, Icon, Text, Button } from "native-base";
import Greeting from '../components/props';

export default class Detail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>   
                    <Text>props: {this.props.item_id}</Text>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Here , the problem is that I need item_id.

(the detail page and the home page run without error)

Comment: Have you also registered the screens in your router?

Comment: <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Drawer 
              key={'Drawer'} 
              hideNavBar={true} 
              contentComponent={Menu} 
              drawerWidth={300} 
              drawerPosition={'left'}
          >
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="home"/>
                    <Scene key="detail" component={Detail} title="detail"/>
          </Drawer>
        </Scene>
      </Router>

Comment: It is being passed, I checked it. Can you try to repro it on [snack](http://snack.expo.io)?